Call `execute-extended-command` with prefilled prefix string
Is it possible to call execute-extended-command with prefilled prefix string? Something like: (execute-extended-command "bmkp-bmenu-").

(defun foo ()
  "..."
  (interactive)
  (command-execute (intern (completing-read "Command: " obarray #'commandp t '("bmkp-bmenu-" . 11)))))

M-x foo, then TAB if you want to see the completions.

command-execute is what's used by execute-extended-command.
The minibuffer prefix text "bmkp-bmenu-" is provided as arg INITIAL-INPUT to completing-read, along with the offset (11) after the prompt, to position the cursor.

